# Logcat Showing Shutting down VM

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse some details from Json. But my app crashes when I navigate to this particular activity where I try to parse the Json. Can anyone please help me fixing the issue.

Here's the screenshot of my log details:
http://prntscr.com/786u34

Comment: Post `onPostExecute` code.

Comment: You're getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Look at line 393 in CompanyProfile_Activity.java and debug from there. Attaching a debugger and configuring it to break on that exception may be helpful. In the future you can just paste the exception text into the question (indented 4 spaces for formatting).